# How can I improve SQL Count performance?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, database-performance, sqlperformance

One of my SQL queries is very slow. I need to COUNT on a table with a total of close to 300,000 records, but it takes 8 seconds for the query to return results.

```
SELECT oc_subject.*, 
      (SELECT COUNT(sid) FROM oc_details 
       WHERE DATE(oc_details.created) > DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
             AND oc_details.sid = oc_subject.id) as totalDetails 
FROM oc_subject 
WHERE oc_subject.status='1' 
ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT " . (int)$start . ", " . (int)$limit;
```

In this way: total 50, Query 8.5837 second

```
SELECT oc_subject.* 
FROM oc_subject 
WHERE oc_subject.status='1' 
ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 0, 50
```

Without Count: total 50, Query 0.0457 second

Comment: Where "without count" means "without that entire subquery"?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I assume so.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev yes, SELECT oc_subject.* FROM oc_subject WHERE oc_subject.status='1' ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 0, 50

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lots of improvements possible:

- Firstly, let's talk about the outer query (main SELECT query) on the `oc_subject` table. This query can take the benefit of [`ORDER BY` Optimization](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/order-by-optimization.html) by using the composite index: `(status, created)`. So, define the following index (if not defined already):

```
ALTER TABLE oc_subject ADD INDEX (status, created);
```

- Secondly, your subquery to get Count is not [Sargeable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799584/what-makes-a-sql-statement-sargable), because of using `Date()` function on the column inside `WHERE` clause. Due to this, it cannot use indexes properly.

Also, `DATE(oc_details.created) > DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)` simply means that you are trying to consider those details which are created on the current date (today). This can be simply written as: `oc_details.created >= CURRENT_DATE` . Trick here is that even if `created` column is of datetime type, MySQL will implictly typecast the `CURRENT_DATE` value to `CURRENT_DATE 00:00:00`.

So change the inner subquery to as follows:

```
SELECT COUNT(sid) 
FROM oc_details 
WHERE oc_details.created >= CURRENT_DATE
      AND oc_details.sid = oc_subject.id
```

- Now, all the improvements on inner subquery will only be useful when you have a proper index defined on the `oc_details` table. So, define the following Composite (and Covering) Index on the `oc_details` table: `(sid, created)`. Note that the order of columns is important here because `created` is a Range condition, hence it should appear at the end. So, define the following index (if not defined already):

```
ALTER TABLE oc_details ADD INDEX (sid, created);
```

- Fourthly, in case of multi-table queries, it is advisable to use [Aliasing](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-alias/), for code clarity (enhanced readability), and avoiding unambiguous behaviour.

So, once you have defined all the indexes (as discussed above),  you can use the following query:

```
SELECT s.*, 
      (SELECT COUNT(d.sid) 
       FROM oc_details AS d
       WHERE d.created >= CURRENT_DATE
             AND d.sid = s.id) as totalDetails 
FROM oc_subject AS s
WHERE s.status='1' 
ORDER BY s.created DESC LIMIT " . (int)$start . ", " . (int)$limit;
```

Comment: Thank you but it took a total of 6.1924 seconds

Comment: @BurakFidancı have you even defined the indexes that I mentioned ?

Comment: My God! My first query did not have any action, but I did try again after your comment and the result is incredible.
0.0034 seconds!

Comment: @BurakFidancı the power of **Proper** indexing :-) Hope you learnt something new today!

Comment: I think the OP wanted `CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY`.

Comment: @RickJames Date(Now() -Interval 1 day) will yesterday date, but then OP is using `>` operator so he want the date to be more than yesterday date, that means curdate

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya - Right you are.

Answer (score 2):

Instead  of several  subquery  (one of each row in your oc_subject table) you could try using a join  on a single subquery grouped  by  sid, and date()

```
  SELECT oc_subject.*, b.count_sid
  FROM oc_subject 
  INNER JOIN  ( 
    SELECT sid, DATE(oc_details.created) date_created, COUNT(sid) count_sid
    FROM oc_details 
    GROUP BY  sid, DATE(oc_details.created)
  ) b on b.sid = oc_subject.id 
      AND b.date_created >  DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
  WHERE oc_subject.status='1' 
  ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT " . (int)$start . ", " . (int)$limit;
```

anyway be careful using php var for limit  ..  be sure you use sanited  values  for  avoid sqlinjection .

Comment: Thank you it took a total of 0.5658 seconds!